# Can't return anything other than 1 or 0 from int function

Tags: c++, function, openframeworks

I wish my first post wasn't so newbie. I've been working with openframeworks, so far so good, but as I'm new to programming I'm having a real headache returning the right value from an int function. I would like the int to increment up until the Boolean condition is met and then decrement to zero. The int is used to move through an array from beginning to end and then back. When I put the guts of the function into the method that I'm using the int in, everything works perfectly, but very messy and I wonder how computationally expensive it is to put there, it just seems that my syntactic abilities are lacking to do otherwise. Advice appreciated, and thanks in advance.

```
int testApp::updown(int j){

if(j==0){
    arp =true;

}
else if (j==7){
    arp = false; 

}

if(arp == true){
    j++;

}

else if(arp == false){
    j--;

}

    return (j);

}
```

and then its called like this in an audioRequest block of the library I'm working with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++){


 if ((int)timer.phasor(sorSpeed)) {

            z = updown(_j);
            noteOut = notes [z];

            cout<<arp;
            cout<<z;

        }
```

EDIT: For addition of some information. Removed the last condition of the second if statement, it was there because I was experiencing strange happenings where j would start walking off the end of the array.

Excerpt of testApp.h

```
int z, _j=0;
Boolean arp;
```

EDIT 2: I've revised this now, it works, apologies for asking something so rudimentary and with such terrible code to go with. I do appreciate the time that people have taken to comment here. Here are my revised .cpp and my .h files for your perusal. Thanks again.

```
#include "testApp.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



testApp::~testApp() {

}

void testApp::setup(){


sampleRate          = 44100;
initialBufferSize   = 1024;

//MidiIn.openPort();
//ofAddListener(MidiIn.newMessageEvent, this, &testApp::newMessage);

j = 0;
z= 0;
state = 1;


tuning = 440;
inputNote = 127;
octave = 4;
sorSpeed = 2;
freqOut = (tuning/32) * pow(2,(inputNote-69)/12);
finalOut = freqOut * octave;



notes[7] = finalOut+640;
notes[6] = finalOut+320;
notes[5] = finalOut+160; 
notes[4] = finalOut+840;
notes[3] = finalOut+160;
notes[2] = finalOut+500;
notes[1] = finalOut+240;
notes[0] = finalOut;


ofSoundStreamSetup(2,0,this, sampleRate, initialBufferSize, 4);/* Call this last ! */


}

void testApp::update(){



}

void testApp::draw(){



}

int testApp::updown(int &_j){

int tmp;

if(_j==0){
    arp = true;
}

else if(_j==7) {
    arp = false; 
}


if(arp == true){
    _j++;
}

else if(arp == false){
    _j--;
}

tmp = _j;
return (tmp);

}

void testApp::audioRequested    (float * output, int bufferSize, int nChannels){


    for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++){


        if ((int)timer.phasor(sorSpeed)) {


            noteOut = notes [updown(z)];


            }


    mymix.stereo(mySine.sinewave(noteOut),outputs,0.5);


    output[i*nChannels    ] = outputs[0]; 
    output[i*nChannels + 1] = outputs[1];

    }
}
```

testApp.h

```
class testApp : public ofBaseApp{

public:
    ~testApp();/* destructor is very useful */
    void setup();
    void update();
    void draw();

    void keyPressed  (int key);
    void keyReleased(int key);
    void mouseMoved(int x, int y );
    void mouseDragged(int x, int y, int button);
    void mousePressed(int x, int y, int button);
    void mouseReleased(int x, int y, int button);
    void windowResized(int w, int h);
    void dragEvent(ofDragInfo dragInfo);
    void gotMessage(ofMessage msg);

    void newMessage(ofxMidiEventArgs &args);

    ofxMidiIn MidiIn;

    void audioRequested     (float * input, int bufferSize, int nChannels); /* output method */
    void audioReceived  (float * input, int bufferSize, int nChannels); /* input method */

    Boolean arp;
    int     initialBufferSize; /* buffer size */
    int     sampleRate;
    int    updown(int &intVar);


    /* stick you maximilian stuff below */

    double filtered,sample,outputs[2];
    maxiFilter filter1;
    ofxMaxiMix mymix;
    ofxMaxiOsc sine1;
    ofxMaxiSample beats,beat;
    ofxMaxiOsc mySine,myOtherSine,timer;

    int currentCount,lastCount,i,j,z,octave,sorSpeed,state;
    double notes[8];
    double noteOut,freqOut,tuning,finalOut,inputNote;
```

};

Comment: Start with a good book on C++, and try again in a week's time after you've worked through some exercises.

Comment: As it seems to me your j in updown() is quite uninitialized and it even wouldn't compile that way. So either you are omitting information within your question, or you deserve the observed behaviour :)

Comment: Where's the declaration of j?

Comment: You don't show the declaration of z, j, or arp. These are all important.

Comment: You have `if (x == true) ... else if (x == false) ... else ...` which is logically impossible. Nothing can every reach the 3rd `else`, unless you've done something absolutely terrible and overridden `operator==` for booleans. There's really too much wrong here to fix, doing so it outside the bounds of StackOverflow's Q/A format. You absolutely need to do what @Kerrek said and *learn* some C++ before you try to write it.

Comment: @Kerrek: We need a new closevote reason. Though I hesitate to call it "new".

Comment: Ah, well I apologise. I meant not to cause offence or waste time, I was just hoping for a helping hand. Close this off if needs be, I'm sure I can figure it out.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Something like "insufficiently well-founded" perhaps... "The post lacks sufficient command of the desired subject area; any useful answer would have to be an entire 'tutorial'."

Comment: Many other StackExchange sites have "general reference" as a reason for closing questions. Supposedly, the reason we don't is because SO is supposed to **become** a "general reference". However, for certain types of problems this is really infeasible... Anyway, to the OP: It would really help if you tried to explain what you are **trying to do**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty hard to piece this all together. I do think you need to go back to basics a bit, but all the same I think I can explain what is going on.

1. You initialise `_j` to `0` and then never modify the value of `_j`.
2. You therefore call `updown` passing `0` as the parameter every time.
3. `updown` returns a value of `1` when the input is `0`.

Perhaps you meant to pass `z` to `updown` when you call it, but I cannot be sure.

Are you really declaring global variables in your header file? That's not good. Try to use local variables and/or parameters as much as possible. Global variables are pretty evil, especially declared in the header file like that!

Comment: Hi David, your comments were massive food for thought. I've solve it now. In retrospect posting this at 2 in the morning with serve codeblindness probably wasn't the best idea. Just like to add, there are no global variables in my program, they are all local to the class or to the scoped the function.

Comment: I still suggest you read a good book about C++ and come back to your problem later.

Comment: Thanks, hochl. But like I say, the problem is sorted.

Comment: In your original post _y was declared in the header file and I assumed it was a global because you did not include context. Was it in fact a member variable? If I answered the original question please mark it as such. If you have a question on your updated code that should be a new question.

Comment: It was a member variable, I've edited the original question to show my entire src. I realise my formatting was less than helpful, thank you for the tips. As you can see, it was issue that I wasn't referencing the the argument properly therefore the function wasn't doing anything at all to the value that I was using. Now, with the "&", it changes the value of the argument, I then use the function to iterate through the array and back.

Comment: The problem was exactly as I described in my answer.